# How do I dynamically start up a custom docker instance for a client

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I am currently designing a cloud service that will serve many users per instance. I would like someone to be able to create their own instance from a webpage which will start up a docker setup with custom naming, and settings using environment variables.

My question is what tools are out there that would allow me to create for example custom docker-compose files with the details provided by the user and fire up an instance for them dynamically? Also if I was to use a subdomain for each instance, how would I dynamically create the mappings for that?

I would be looking to deploy on AWS using docker and NGINX.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? I have had some good experiences using a combination of Python, Jinja2, YAML, docker-compose, and Nginx to create composable web services with variable configurations. I take advantage of the fact that you can have multiple ```-f``` switches on a ```docker-compose``` command line and you can use a wildcard include in an Nginx configuration like this: ```include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am currently in the research stage at the moment but there are some backend services that have a basic proof of concept and also a frontend in Angular. I am looking into the deployment side of things. I have been looking at ECS recently and am thinking that would be a great solution to host but still unsure how I would dynamically launch a new instance and have the mappings configured. I guess the whole setup can be configured with variables to be passed in and I would to build a configuration file to define them.

Comment: You might consider using a local k8s configuration for development. This would then easily deploy and scale on the "cloud".